# Login Using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Thank in advance.. this is my first question here..
i'm working on php login script, my script is almost ready here is a code

**HTML FORM**

```
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" />
</input type='submit' id="submit"/>
<div id='result'></div>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({                    
      url: 'login.php',     
      type: 'post',
      data: { username: $('#username').val(),  password: $('#password').val() }, 
      dataType: 'json',                   
      success: function(data)         
      {
      } 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Password']);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass' LIMIT 1");
    $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if ($userCount ==1) 
    {
        echo "login success!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong detail!";
    }
}
```

What i want is to show login.php result in  my html form.. i have div in my html form

```
<div id='result'></div>
```

Can someone please help me.. and thanks again to all

**UPDATE**

I tried this but it was not working

```
 success: function(data)         
  {
    $('#result').html(data);
  }
```

Comment: you should first understand how to get response using ajax.then how to set html to a html element.two different duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one line code in your ajax success function.i hope it is helpfull for you.

```
<script>
 $('#submit').click(function() {
$.ajax({                    
  url: 'login.php',     
  type: 'post',
  data: { username: $('#username').val(),  password: $('#password').val() }, 
  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(data)         
  {
    $('#result').html(data);
  } 
}); });
</script>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: in your success function try to  alert(data); and show what you get?

Comment: yes it' working on alert but it does not show data in a div

Answer (score 0):

```
 success: function(data)         
 {
   // you can do whatever you want to do here..e.g.
   if(data=="login success!"){ ///
    //redirect to home page  
   } 
   else alert("Invalid credentials");
 }
```